# webcam does not work (solved)

Tags: webcam

I'm newbie in Linux, I installed elementary os recently on **Sony cr115e** and webcam didn't work.
`lsusb`

> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
> Bus 006 Device 002: ID 054c:02c1 Sony Corp. 
> Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
> Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 05ca:1839 Ricoh Co., Ltd Visual Communication Camera VGP-VCC6 [R5U870]
> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
> Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
> Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub

then I tried 
`sudo modprobe uvcvideo`     
and nothing.

Answer (score 1):

after 2 day trying I fixed  it by:
my laptop webcam is *05ca:1839* and the driver is **r5u87x**.
so I did these steps:
`wget https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/development/rawhide/Everything/aarch64/os/Packages/r/r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-15.a9b2171d762b.fc33.aarch64.rpm`
for converting from rpm to deb 
`sudo add-apt-repository universe` 
`sudo apt-get install alien` 
`sudo alien r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-15.a9b2171d762b.fc33.aarch64.rpm` 
for installing deb file:
`sudo dpkg -i r5u87x-firmware_0.2.0-16_amd64.deb`
adn `sudo apt-get install libglib*-dev libusb-dev build-essential gcc automake mercurial`
for enabling
`xinput --list`
`xinput enable 7`
and 
`sudo modprobe -v uvcvideo`
`sudo modprobe uvcvideo`
restart and enjoy.

Answer (score -1):

@msallehi
I tried to follow the instructions and there seems to be some error with the links above (space between /Everything/ and aarch64).

In any case I got to the point where you convert from rpm to deb and it failed. See steps I took.

```
sudo wget https://download1.rpmfusion.org/nonfree/fedora/development/rawhide/Everything/aarch64/os/Packages/r/r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm

sudo add-apt-repository universe

sudo apt-get install alien

sudo alien r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-15.a9b2171d762b.fc33.aarch64.rpm

warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
warning: r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID 94843c65: NOKEY
r5u87x-firmware-0.2.0-16.a9b2171d762b.fc34.aarch64.rpm is for architecture aarch64 ; the package cannot be built on this system
```

Now I am stuck. Seems that the Kubuntu version I am using doesn't like it...

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The "aarch64" architecture is for 64-bit ARM chips. You are likely running a 64-bit Intel for AMD chip. You will need to download the correct file for your CPU, or use a flag in alien like ` --target=amd64`